# setOnInfoWindowClickListener for a Marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I've created a marker called "Pin" and I'm trying to get an activity/Class open when it's window is clicked.
From what I have so far, the activity will open but when any marker's window is clicked.

I want to get it to open when the marker Pin's window is clicked.

The Class I wanted to open is "holyStone".

```
private void holystone() 
    {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LatLng pos = new LatLng(52.972869, -9.427004);
        Marker Pin = theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()

                .title("Holy Stone of Clonrichert")
                .snippet("Holy Stone of Clonrichert has been upgraded to a class two relic by the Vatican.")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
                .position(pos)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))


        );
        // below displays the window...remove this!!!
        //Pin.showInfoWindow();

            Pin.isInfoWindowShown();
        this.theMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker Pin) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, holyStone.class);
               startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Any suggestions would be great, Thanks for looking.

Comment: Your description is not clear and sounds a bit contradictory. Please clarify when the activity window does open and when it doesn't now.

Comment: Sorry, I basically want to open the holyStone.class to open when Marker Pin's InfoWindow is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using an if else statement.

I added markers at the start, just after before the onCreate method.

e.g protected static Marker Pin = null;
    protected static Marker Casino = null;

```
if(Casino.isInfoWindowShown()){
                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TheRock.class);
                   startActivity(intent);

                    }

                    else if(Pin.isInfoWindowShown()){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, holyStone.class);

                        startActivity(intent);
                        }
                }
```

If you have any questions about my answer please ask.
Thanks.